# Old color film effect & pin-up poster effect

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I've noticed that old color movies have a certain look about them, a certain film effect that is hard to come across in modern video - the colors are kind of matted out, like seen through a canvas of some sort - ([example](http://emol.org/movies/mclintock/index.html) - column on the left). Is there any filtering algorithm that could apply this effect to video? On a side note, an equally interesting and related aspect would be the vintage pin-up posters effect - like the ones featured in the Fallout 3 game. I found on the internet a way to reproduce that in [Photoshop](http://www.planetphotoshop.com/pin-up-effect.html), yet it's a complicated series of careful steps... anyone know of a publicly available image processing algorithm that could save me the work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called [bleach bypass](http://www.finalcolor.com/bleach.htm), and an implementation can be found in HLSL [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/shaderlibrary/packages/post_bleach_bypass.fx.zip), on the NVIDIA Developer page.

Answer (score 1):

To my non-artistic eyes, the movie effect you link to seems to just be a very low contrast ratio, perhaps accompanied by an increase in overall brightness.

Comment: *"very low contrast ratio"* is too strong, but low contrast and bright.